# LDAP to gitlab user sync for oauth token

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I am working with gitlab rest API, and gitlab is connected to LDAP too.

Now I am facing an issue is that if I add a  user to LDAP store, this user need to do at least one sign in via web UI to get access token through API (/oauth/token)

My requirement is any users whose are added directly to LDAP need to generate access token through gitlab API without doing any sign in via web UI, please let me know the possible solution.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Good morning Jamsheer,

That makes sense, since otherwise you would automatically create accounts for all the users in your LDAP, with the possibility of running out of licenses.

Currently there is an open issue where this is being discussed, with the possibility of creating all the LDAP users as deactivated and active them after the first login.

- [Add a way for LDAP users to be created before first login](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/699)

In any case, this is not in place yet.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there any other way to sync ldap users to gitlab. I have created ldap users to gitlab via API, but here the problem is if we change the password in ldap that will not be effect in gitlab. Just for your info, here, LDAP store is acting as the backend of our identity store

Comment: Do you mean that you have created standard users with the API using the LDAP data? That shouldn't be a problem either, as soon as they log at least once with their LDAP credentials, the standard account will connect with the LDAP DN. But of course their credentials as standard user will still be enabled if you don't disable them manually. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/admin_area/settings/sign_in_restrictions.html#password-authentication-enabled

Comment: Thank you @Daniel My requirement is, our users will not use gitlab UI, but from other application, they need to invoke gitlab API. 
And also that application connected to open LDAP, So here we are expecting if any new user added to LDAP they need to get gitlab token without do any login via gitlab UI

Comment: please let me know if any option is available

Comment: As I mentioned, this is not possible at the moment. Any new user in the LDAP will require to log at least once in GitLab with their LDAP credentials in order to be created in GitLab, otherwise they won't exist in the platform. Even if you create before the user with the API with the same email than the LDAP account, the user will have to log with their LDAP credentials at least once in the GitLab UI in order to connect that account with LDAP.

Comment: Thank you for the reply :)